# C++ Am I adding and accessing my Vector correctly?

Tags: c++, vector, crash, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am creating an object and adding it to a `std::vector` and then later on accessing the `std::vector` to use member variables from the objects I place in it.

.h that contains the `std::vector`

```
std::vector<Field *> vFields;
inline std::vector<Field *> getFields() { return vFields; };
```

In the .cpp I do this:

```
Field* f1 = Field::createWithLocation(ccp( p.x, p.y));
addChild(f1->getFieldSprite(), 2);
getFields().push_back(f1); // add the new field to a container
//vFields.push_back(f1); // add the new field to a container

std::cout << "add - # of Fields: " << getFields().size() << std::endl;
```

When instantiating the `Field* f1` above this is happening:

```
Field* Field::createWithLocation(cocos2d::CCPoint p)
{
    Field* f = new Field();
    //f->autorelease();
    f->initWithLocation(p);
    return f;
}

void Field::initWithLocation(cocos2d::CCPoint p)
{
    setFieldCenterPoint(p);
    setFieldGraphicName(FIELD::fieldIconFileName);

    setFieldSprite(cocos2d::CCSprite::create(getFieldGraphicName().c_str()));
     getFieldSprite()->setPosition(ccp(getFieldCenterPoint().x, getFieldCenterPoint().y));

    setFieldSize(getFieldSprite()->getContentSize());

    setFieldNumber(7159);

    setFieldTag(7159);

    std::cout << "When Field Created #: " << getFieldTag() << std::endl;
}
```

This works fine and when the `Field` object is created the std::vector says `1` in `size()` and the getFieldTag() returns `7159` like it was set.

The problem is when I go to access the `Field` from the vector something happens and I crash. I found that if I output getTagNumber() it is way different.

Example of accessing the vector:

```
else if (getFieldLayerState() == kActive)
{
    // so did they click on a field?
    std::cout << "Field Layer Status Is Active" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "touch - # of Fields: " << vFields.size() << std::endl;

    // Loop through the field vector and get the size of each field and see if it was tapped    
    for (int f=0; f<vFields.size(); f++)
    {
        //field = (Field*) getFields().at(f);
        Field* field = (Field*) vFields.at(f);

        std::cout << "field #: "<< field->getFieldNumber() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "field tag: "<< field->getFieldTag() << std::endl;

        if (field->getFieldSprite()->boundingBox().containsPoint(location))
        {
            std::cout << "touched field #: "<< field->getFieldNumber() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "touched field tag: "<< field->getFieldTag() << std::endl;
            _dir->Instance()->getAudioEngine()->playBackgroundMusic("tap.mp3", false);    
        }
     }
}
```

Sample Output from the cout statements:

```
When Field Created #: 7159
add - # of Fields: 1
Field Layer Status Is Active

touch - # of Fields: 1
field #: 1769234804
field tag: 353394533`
```

I crash at the `if (field->getFieldSprite()->boundingBox().containsPoint(location))` line above with an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` and it is clear that what is in the vector has changed from what I put in it, or so it seems.

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [The rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) might be helpful.

Comment: Do you touch `f1` after it's inserted into the vector? This looks as if somebody released memory occupied by the `Field` object.

Comment: right now `f1` is placed in the vector after creation and I am just accessing pieces from it, but yes I will be modifying it also

Comment: so for the `rule of three` you are saying that a class should always implement its own versions of `destructor`, `copy constructor`, 
`copy assignment operator`

Comment: I mean does your code contain something like `delete f1` or do you delete some pointers from the vector? And by the way, you do not need type cast here: `Field* field = (Field*) vFields.at(f);`. If you need the type cast `(Field*)`, then it's probably the wrong vector.

Comment: @inspired good point about the type cast. This vector always contains `Field*` I have an `f->autorelease();` statement when I create the object which is a cocos2d-x feature.

Comment: OMG, it is the `autorelease`causing the crash. Commenting that out and things work every time. so that means I should manually `delete` in the destructor. So multiple issues. I needed to return a `reference` and the `autorelease`

Answer (score 0):

Your `getFields` function returns a *copy* of the vector. So any changes to the returned vector will only happen in the copy, and not the original.

You want to return a *reference*.

```
std::vector<Field*>& getFields() { return vFields; }
//                 ^
// Note the ampersand
```

You might also want to add a `const` overload of the function as well:

```
const std::vector<Field*>& getFields() const { return vFields; }
// ^                                      ^
// Note the two `const` modifiers, the last one is important
```

Then if you modify the vector, e.g. by adding to it, the compiler will select the first non-const overload. And if you don't modify the vector, e.g. when you just call `size` on the vector, the compiler will select the second const overload.

Comment: is that the case with all `get` and `set` like ints, strings, etc?

Comment: But is still happens if I use the vector directly without a `getter` like:  `Field* field = (Field*) vFields.at(f);` I made an edit above in the `for` loop to show it

Comment: @Jason It depends. If you have separate setter and getter functions then you should not return references. But in this case, since you modify the vector you need to return a reference.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg An excellent point. And I do not understand how does getFields().size() ever becomes 1 (or the output does not correspond to the code). However, returning a copy should only fail when modifying the vector, it shouldn't lead to an incorrect data in the vector itself?

Comment: why would `getFields().size()` not be `1`? I add to it when I create the object `getFields().push_back(f1); // add the new field to a container`

Comment: @Jason Just because you add the item to the copy of the vector. When the statement is done, that copy is destructed, and the next call to `getFields` returns a brand new copy.

Comment: oh, so making the `get` return a `reference` fixes that

Comment: To extend this, is the rule to always return a `reference` version if you plan to use a `get` or 'set' to modify?

Comment: @Jason You can actually have two overloads of the same function, one returning a modifiable vector, and one `const` overload to return a non-modifiable vector. Just like the vector `operator[]` function. Then the compiler will pick the best one. See my modified answer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Thanks for explaining this. it is the const that makes it return a non modifiable version.